# How to pass the the returned value of the first promise to the last one in a chained promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a confusing problem:

I am using promise chain to call couple of functions as follows:

```
 CommonPromiseLists.checkStatusPromise().then(CommonPromiseLists.getChannelPreferencePromise).then(CommonPromiseLists.getChannelsPromise).then(getUniqueStory.bind(null, storyId))
```

As you see the functions are called consequently and I get the right results. However based on the recent requirement changes now I need to pass the return value of the CommonPromiseLists.checkStatusPromise() to getUniqueStory.bind(null, storyId) which is the last promise I call. I have a solution in mind: so whenever I return and hand in the the returned value to the next promise I can include the returned value of the first promise as well. But I believe there should be an easier way. Is there any better way I can grab the returned value of the checkStatusPromise() and pass it to getUniqueStory.bind(null, storyId, the return value of the first promise)?

Comment: Are you using babel to compile your code?

Comment: @gargantuan Yes I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the results through the promise chain, but that makes the code tightly coupled, requiring the succeeding callbacks to anticipate a strange structure as the resolved value.

Using plain promises, an easier way to do it is to enclose the rest of the operation in the `checkStatusPromise` callback. That way, `checkStatusPromise`'s result is exposed.

```
CommonPromiseLists.checkStatusPromise().then(res => {
  return CommonPromiseLists.getChannelPreferencePromise(res)
    .then(CommonPromiseLists.getChannelsPromise)
    .then(getUniqueStory.bind(null, storyId, res)) // access res
});
```

If you can use async-await, it becomes a bit easier:

```
async enclosingFunction(){
  const status = await CommonPromiseLists.checkStatusPromise();
  const channelPreference = await CommonPromiseLists.getChannelPreferencePromise(status);
  const channels = await CommonPromiseLists.getChannelsPromise(channelPreference);
  const uniqueStory = await getUniqueStory.bind(null, storyId, res)
  return uniqueStory;
}

enclosingFunction().then(value => /* results */)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complete answer I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Promises might not be what you need to use here. It looks like you need either a generator or async/await. I'll use async/await here as it might be easier to understand.

Imagine you have a function that returns a promise like this

```
function double(someVal) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(someVal * 2);
        }, 2000);
      });
}
```

You could the use async/await like this

```
async function sumMultiplications() {
    var a = await double(5);
    var b = await double(20);
    var c = await double(a);
    return a + b + c;
}
```

> When an async function is called, it returns a Promise. When the async
>   function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the
>   returned value.  When the async function throws an exception or some
>   value, the Promise will be rejected with the thrown value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. For anyone who see this post I would suggest to read this answer to get a better idea

Answer (score 0):

Just save result if you needed:

```
let res;
func1().then(result=>{
    res = result;
    return func2();
})
.then(func3)
.then(func4)
...
then(result=>{
  ...
  return res; //return result that you save as result of the first promise
})
.catch(err=>{
  throw err;
})
```

If you want omits some steps you can do like this:

```
let res;

func1().then(result=>{
    res = result;
    if(res) //you check of the result
       return func2().then(func3);
    else 
       return func4();
})
then(result=>{
  ...
  return res; //return result that you save as result of the first promise
})
.catch(err=>{
  throw err;
})
```

Comment: So this can I send res to fun4 or should I wait for all calls to finish?

Comment: If you want omits some steps see I'm changed the answer